# Windows 10 not outputting sound when connecting HDMI to TV

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi

I am used to using my windows 10 laptop to connect to my TV and watch stuff. I do this all the time,  however recently the sound has stopped working. To be clear the video works but the sound does not. I have tried another HDMI cable and this does not solve the problem which suggests that its something to the with the settings in windows 10 causing the issue. Does anybody have any idea what the issue might be?

My computer us working fine, sound works without HDMI attached. Volume is up and everything is working on the computer side of things. Nothing has recently been installed either...The only problem is that when you connect the TV to the laptop the video works but the sounds does not.

Comment: This is a little broad to be answered with any specificity. Can you tell us what you have checked? Is the TV muted? Are the sound options in Windows 10 muted? Has there been a recent driver update? Have you tried system restore back to a date it was working? More details about the PC might help too...and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the Desktop, find the  volume icon on the Taskbar.
2. Right-click on Volume button and select the Playback devices.
3. In the list, find the one for your HDMI Output. If it isn't there you probably need to update the drivers for the graphic card hosting the HDMI port.
4. Right-click the HDMI Output device for your TV connection and select "Test". You should hear the chimes bouncing between the speakers and see the green level bars bouncing on the device. (Make sure your TV isn't muted or turned down to 0 volume)
5. Assuming (4) went well, Right click the device and select "Select as Default Device"
6. Restart your program which is sending output and you should hear it now.

Windows 10 seems pretty clever about selecting the HDMI for you when you have that plugged in and reverting to the other default when it isn't but you may be visiting the "Playback Devices" dialog to reset things.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve just solved my problem of no sound via HDMI on Windows 10 on an Acer E5-571 laptop.
On several previous occasions I had tried reinstalling Intel (R) HD Graphics Famly 15.40.3.4248 without it solving the problem. 
This time I (re)installed the Intel Chipset Driver 10.1.1.7 first and then reinstalled Intel (R) HD Graphics Famly 15.40.3.4248 and the cause of the trouble (Microsoft’s HD Audio Device) had disappeared and my TV showed up as a device for audio playback with sound on the HDMI connection.

Answer (score 0):

I had also a similar issue: TV not showing in Sound devices on Ideapad 530S IKB14 + Windows 10. After installing a few times a bunch of drivers, the problem was solved after I performed 2 actions:
+1. Uninstall Hyper-V Windows feature: Start -> Turn windows features on or off -> Untick Hyper-V.
+2. Reset BIOS to defaults.
Not sure which one did the trick but now I can play movies on TV from my laptop. What a big achievement!
Hope this help.